# Document.write in Clojurescript?

Tags: clojurescript

It's very often convenient to be able to print things in a simple way when debugging.

How do I call document.write in Clojurescript?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like so:

```
(.write js/document "hey")
```

Comment: For some reason this overwrites all the HTML sometimes when done from Lighttable

Comment: `document.write` normally overwrites the entire page if called after the page has loaded.